# How to swap two pair bytes in Python 3

Tags: python, struct

I have a bytestring it multiple 4 bytes. Each 4 bytes is a float but for each 4 bytes first two bytes and next two bytes need to be swapped.

example:

```
input = b'\x00\x00@\xb9a\xa8\xbdf'
struct.unpack('f', b'\x00\x00@\xb9') #-0.00018310546875 is incorrect
struct.unpack('>f', b'\x00\x00@\xb9') #2.3218114255397894e-41 is incorrect
struct.unpack('>f', b'@\xb9\x00\x00') # 5.78125 is correct
```

How i can easy swap two hi bytes and two low bytes?

Next code is correct

```
h = b''
for i in range(0, len(input), 4):
    h += struct.pack('BBBB', *(d[i+2],d[i+3],d[i],d[i+1]))
struct.unpack('>ff', h) # is correct (5.78125, -0.05624547600746155)
```

but may be there are another more easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
>>> a = b'\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf0'
>>> ''.join( [chr(a[i^2]) for i in range(len(a))] )
'Vx\x124Þð\x9a¼'
>>>
```

You don't even need to use a `struct` for that.

Comment: no, your code reverses the byte order, i want to swap pairs of bytes(words). 
Like this magic_func(b'\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf0') == b'\x56\x78\x12\x34\xde\xf0\x9a\xbc'

Comment: @dzukp please, check the updated answer, hope it works for you too =)